# What expression/logic do I need to put in a script that checks a log that changes everyday as it has the date embedded in it

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

How can I reference a log file that changes everyday in the script below

```
#!/bin/bash
#Written By *****
#Date:13th March 2017

cd /var/opt/logs/session/

egrep "9450=|9451=|9452=" 2017-03-13-PDK-AP-LXFXMR-01*.log > /home/user/l.log
```

tomorrow I will need to change the below manually

```
egrep "9450=|9451=|9452=" 2017-03-14-PDK-AP-LXFXMR-01*.log > /home/user/l.log
```

Is there a way to egrep but specify the below as

`date +'%Y-%m-%d'` instead of `2017-03-14`

```
egrep "9450=|9451=|9452=" date +'%Y-%m-%d'-PDK-AP-LXFXMR-01*.log > /home/user/l.log
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "check", but you can generate today's expected filename by

```
filename="$(date +%Y-%M-%d)-PDK-AP-BBBBB-01-session.log"
```

and then use `"$filename"` in your script. Is that what you need?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Please specify "didn't work": what did `filename` contain instead?

Comment: @DjOlu your question isn't clear. A response of "it didn't work" isn't clear. The answer offered here builds a filename that is appropriate for the current date. If that's not what you want you need to tell us that by editing your question and providing the additional information.

Comment: @DjOlu From your edit, this appears to be exactly the right answer. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: @mattdm 2 I get the below  $ grep: date: No such file or directory
-bash: grep:: command not found
 $ grep: +%Y-%m-%d-AP-IXFXMR-01*.log: No such file or directory

Comment: @DjOlu What do you get if you type (exactly — cut and paste it as one line) `filename="$(date +%Y-%M-%d)-PDK-AP-BBBBB-01-session.log"; echo $filename`?

Comment: @DjOlu In the last line of your edited question the `date ...` is given as an argument to the egrep directly instead of being executed. Thus, grep searches for a file named `date`, which it doesn't find. Put it in backticks or in `$()` dollar-brackets, to replace it by the answer to the executed command: `egrep "9450=|9451=|9452=" $(date +'%Y-%m-%d')-PDK-AP-LXFXMR-01*.log > /home/user/l.log`

Comment: @mattdm and Philippos Thanks this actually work I had an unwanted space